# Overflow icon 3 dot not appearing

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

[image]I saw many posts in SO but couldn't figure out why Overflow icon is not displayed. I am testing on real device Android 4.4 . I get the items displayed on bottom of the screen when options button is pressed . But I need it to appear as 3 dot menu on Top Right like in Gmail App. Pl help. Need something like attached pic of Tubemate app when options button clicked.

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--xmlns:com.app.MainActivity="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"-->

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="search"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_end"
    android:icon="@drawable/end"
    android:menuCategory="container"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/end"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>

 </menu>
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{   menu.clear();

this.menu = menu;
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_end:
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    case R.id.action_search:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: do oyu see the items on pressing hardware menu button?

Comment: then it works the way it should. Don't worry.

Comment: But I need the 3 dot icon.:(

Comment: Quoting docs "The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. Phones with menu keys display the action overflow when the user presses the key". Read http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: So it means if I need to display 3 dot like Gmail App I need to forcibly allow overflow using the code posted below by @fida1989 ?

Comment: well i don't know about wrokaround. sorry can't comment on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overflow menu will only appear on devices that don't have physical menu button. In devices with physical menu button it will appear from bottom.

To force overflow menu, put this code inside **onCreate**:

```
try {
ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
if (menuKeyField != null) {
menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

[Source](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/08/06/android-always-show-the-overflow-menu-even-if-the-phone-as-a-menu/)

Comment: Is it the right way to do it? Even Apps like Gmail are following this piece of code?Wont it display 3 dot without this code?

Comment: In devices that have menu button you need this code. Don't know about what gmail app did exactly.

Comment: Your solution works great . I hope this doesn't create any compatibility issues with devices below 4.4 ,does it? I am accepting your answer. Thanks :)